# How many ways 5 different books be distributed among 5 students

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I've seen this question in a book and can't figure it out correctly.

> Let 5 different books be distributed among 5 students. Suppose the
>   books are returned and distributed to the students again later on. In
>   how many ways the books be distributed so that no student will get the
>   same book twice?

Answer for that question is :

> 5280

My answer :
At first,the 5 books can be distributed to 5 students in 5! ways.Then after returning,the books can be distributed in $4^5$ ways so that no student will get the same book twice.So the answer will be 5!x$4^5$ ways.

Can anyone please explain?

Comment: Are there five rounds of book distribution (such that every student eventually gets to read all books), or only two?

Comment: **HINT:** Take a look at derangments.
[Wikipedia.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement)

Comment: And $4^5$ definitely overcounts the second distribution, because that includes some options where multiple students get the same book -- for example `ABCDE` followed by `EEEEA`.

Comment: @Henning Makholm : There are only two. 1st the 5 books will bistributed to five students and will be returned and next they will be again distributed so that no student gets same book twice.

Comment: @Teja713 $5! < 4^5$ but the different combinations should be smaller number since it excludes some of the ways of $5!$

Comment: @Complex1238877 : I found my mistake. I over calculated some terms. I used derangments to find the answer.

Comment: Yes, derangements is the right thing to calculate. Then it depends what you are counting, whether it's both the initial distribution and also the ways to redistribute with no fixed points, or just the latter, or...